# how can i display an html file in another HTML file using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Currently i get a separate HTML file using XMLHttpRequest and request a document leaving me with an [object HTMLDocument]. I take this object and put it in the HTML file i'm currently working on so it hopefully displays the game inside the [object HTMLDocument].
if you console.log([object HTMLDocument]) you get ↓ which is the code for the game. The game uses JavaScript to run.

```
#document
<!doctype html>
<html lang=​"en" dir=​"ltr">​
  <head>​
    <meta charset=​"utf-8">
    ​<title>​My Game​</title>
    <script type=​"text/​javascript" src=​"phaser.min.js">​</script>
  </head>
​   <body>
    ​ <script type=​"text/​javascript" src=​"game.js">​</script>
   </body>​
</html>​
```

Here is the element tree you get for the main HTML file when you try to put the document object in a shadow element.↓

```
<div id="somethin">
  ↓#shadow-root(open)  
      "[Object HTMLDocument]"  <-console.log this shows everything is there ↑
div
```

This is the code i use to make the document object, and put it in a shadow element. Is there any way to make this work using XMLHttpRequest, using different response types, etc, so the game displays inside a container of my choosing? When i do it like this all i get is text in the container saying [object HtmlDocument].

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', '../my first game/myhtml.html', true);
xhr.responseType='document';
xhr.send();

xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
    alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
  } else { // show the result
    alert(`Done, got ${xhr.response.length} bytes`);
     // responseText is the server\
     myFunction(xhr);

  }
};

xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
  if (event.lengthComputable) {
    alert(`Received ${event.loaded} of ${event.total} bytes`);
  } else {
    alert(`Received ${event.loaded} bytes`); // no Content-Length
  }

};

xhr.onerror = function(xml) {
  alert("Request failed");
};


function myFunction(myvar) {
  var test=myvar.response
  var x=document.getElementById("somethin");
  var tester=x.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

  console.log(test);
  tester.innerHTML=test;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reasons why would anyone do anything like this. Why are you loading your game this way? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Im trying to make a website, that showcases all the websites, or projects that i made in one place. Im trying to figure out a way without using Iframes, or <object><embed>, or import since its getting depricated.

Comment: I see. Why don't you just use <a href="your local url">My site</a>?  Create links in a HTML and refer to your other HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `responseText` property of XMLHttpRequest object instead of `response` property (1st line of `myFunction`).

Comment: I dont think responseText works on document objects. Im currently reading an article on how to do what i set out to do. So if i find an answer ill post it.